# Program to pass string from one view to another?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ipad

I have an iphone application containing two views
 The first view have a button, now
i want to show the title of the button on the second view when that button is clicked.
         How  can i do it because if we save the title into a string ,the string get emptied when second view is loaded ?

Comment: Please don't abuse the mod flag.  If you want attention for this question, add a bounty.

Comment: In what situations mod flag should be used?

Comment: Here is an excellent PDF for starting out "Xcoders" -- http://www.macxfire.com/documentation/BecomeAnXcoder.pdf

Comment: please whoever vote down ,do give reasons so i can correct my mistake

Comment: I dont know whats wrong with my question as it has got two downvotes ? I would like to know if anybody care

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the interface declare the string and make a property:

```
 @interface MyViewController : UIViewController {


   NSString *string_i_want_to_set;  

 }

 @property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *string_i_want_to_set;

 @end
```

In the implementation synthesize the string after @implementation MyViewController like this:

```
 #import "MyViewController.h"


 @implementation MyViewController

 @synthesize string_i_want_to_set;

 // OTHER CODE HERE...

 @end
```

Then when you alloc/init the view controller you can set the property like this:

```
MyViewController *myVC = [[MyViewController alloc] init];
myVC.string_i_want_to_set = @"...."
```

Hope this gives you more detail.

Thanks
James

Comment: A couple suggestions for this answer: you don't need to declare an ivar for a property, usually Cocoa / CocoaTouch devs use camelCase instead of underscores_between_words, usually string properties are declared as 'copy' rather than 'retain', either way you should release your string property in dealloc.

Answer (score 0):

you can make object of second view and can pass string to it

view2object.view2string=@"anything"   or label.text;